# CSS stop div height from extending past viewport + make topnav stick when scrolling

Tags: html, css, layout, height

I haven't done much frontend - My question is twofold, my .row div is pushing past the `viewport` when height is set to 100% - I'm guessing this is to do with the relative/fixed position interaction between the topnav and the sidebar? How do I fix this? And how do I make the `topbar` remain in the viewport when I scroll? position: fixed breaks the formatting.

I've also had to give column2 a left margin to stop it sliding behind the sidebar - is this the best way to approach it?

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
    height: 100%;
}
.row{
  height: 100%;
}
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.topnav{
 background-color: whitesmoke;
 color: rgb(91, 27, 143);
    text-decoration: bold;
    font-size: 12pt;
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 6%;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #b338a9bb;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 2;
}
.column1 {
 float: left;
    width: 15%;
    padding: 15px;
    height: 100%; /* Full-height: remove this if you want "auto" height */
    position: fixed; /* Fixed Sidebar (stay in place on scroll) */
    z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
    background-color: lightgray; /* Black */
    overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
}
.column2 {
 float: left;
    width: 60%;
    padding: 15px;
 margin-left: 15%;
 height: 100%;
}
.column3 {
 float: left;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 15px;
 border-left: 2px solid lightgray;
 height: 100%;
}
.button{
    background-color: #b338a9bb;
    border: 2px solid #b338a9bb;
    border-radius: 12px;
    color: whitesmoke;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    max-height: 50px;
}
.button:hover{
    color: #424242;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border: 2px solid #b338a9bb;
}
.button:focus{
    outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>


<div class="topnav">
  <div style="float: right;padding-right: 5px; padding-top: 10px;">
  <button class="button" href="#">logout</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column1">
    <h2>Column</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet pretium urna. Vivamus venenatis velit nec neque ultricies, eget elementum magna tristique. Quisque vehicula, risus eget aliquam placerat, purus leo tincidunt eros, eget luctus quam orci in velit. Praesent scelerisque tortor sed accumsan convallis.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column2">
    <h2>Column</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet pretium urna. Vivamus venenatis velit nec neque ultricies, eget elementum magna tristique. Quisque vehicula, risus eget aliquam placerat, purus leo tincidunt eros, eget luctus quam orci in velit. Praesent scelerisque tortor sed accumsan convallis.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column3">
    <h2>Column</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet pretium urna. Vivamus venenatis velit nec neque ultricies, eget elementum magna tristique. Quisque vehicula, risus eget aliquam placerat, purus leo tincidunt eros, eget luctus quam orci in velit. Praesent scelerisque tortor sed accumsan convallis.</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1xgqjown/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using a percentage height for the navbar, instead use:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
height: 60px;
width: 100%;
```

For column2 and column3 use:

```
height: 100vh;
margin-top: 60px; (to offset the height of the navbar)
```

Comment: How come you wouldn’t use a percentage height for navbar?

Comment: @anxxxious For mobile views etc, 6% is very small.

Comment: Thanks man, that worked but I had to use `body{padding-top: 60px}` to stop the divs clipping the navbar.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the position for topnav to fixed

```
.topnav{
    position: fixed;
}
```

Then it will stay in place even on scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Use     `position: fixed;` and  `width:100%` and `topnav`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
.row{
  height: 100%;
}
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.topnav{
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  color: rgb(91, 27, 143);
  text-decoration: bold;
  font-size: 12pt;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 6%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #b338a9bb;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  width:100%
}
.column1 {
  float: left;
  width: 15%;
  padding: 15px;
  height: 100%; /* Full-height: remove this if you want "auto" height */
  position: fixed; /* Fixed Sidebar (stay in place on scroll) */
  z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
  background-color: lightgray; /* Black */
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
}
.column2 {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-left: 15%;
  height: 100%;
}
.column3 {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 15px;
  border-left: 2px solid lightgray;
  height: 100%;
}
.button{
   background-color: #b338a9bb;
   border: 2px solid #b338a9bb;
   border-radius: 12px;
   color: whitesmoke;
   transition-duration: 0.4s;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 8px 15px;
   text-align: center;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 20px;
   width: 100px;
   max-height: 50px;
}
.button:hover{
    color: #424242;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border: 2px solid #b338a9bb;
}
.button:focus{
    outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>


<div class="topnav">
  <div style="float: right;padding-right: 5px; padding-top: 10px;">
  <button class="button" href="#">logout</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column1">
    <h2>Column</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet pretium urna. Vivamus venenatis velit nec neque ultricies, eget elementum magna tristique. Quisque vehicula, risus eget aliquam placerat, purus leo tincidunt eros, eget luctus quam orci in velit. Praesent scelerisque tortor sed accumsan convallis.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column2">
    <h2>Column</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet pretium urna. Vivamus venenatis velit nec neque ultricies, eget elementum magna tristique. Quisque vehicula, risus eget aliquam placerat, purus leo tincidunt eros, eget luctus quam orci in velit. Praesent scelerisque tortor sed accumsan convallis.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column3">
    <h2>Column</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sit amet pretium urna. Vivamus venenatis velit nec neque ultricies, eget elementum magna tristique. Quisque vehicula, risus eget aliquam placerat, purus leo tincidunt eros, eget luctus quam orci in velit. Praesent scelerisque tortor sed accumsan convallis.</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use these properties of top nav

```
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 70px; //or whatever you want
```